# Comparing two vectors in the most effective way

Tags: c++

Basically I am trying to record the animation of an application. I am doing this by frame by frame recording.

So what I do is I record a frame (all the meta data of the animation) and compare it with the previous frame. If any of the objects aren't in the previous frame then I save them and do stuff with them that I don't want you guys to know :P

Now the problem is time efficiency. I want to be able to complete this function within half a second because it has to be called again after half a second. The size of frames will get around `1000-1500`.

I checked set_difference and other methods and I think that wont be enough for me because, first of all I have meta data which cant be sorted I would have to make lots of changes and even if I included a sorting criteria, the sorting of 2 vectors and then comparing them is computationally expensive.

Right now the best I came up with is;

just an example not my real code

```
auto itr1 = list1.begin();
auto itr2 = list2.begin();

for (i; i<total_items;i++)
{
    if (*itr1 != *itr2)
        do something
        itr1++; itr2++;
    }
}
```

This is the best i came up with and its complexity is n. Now it works if both the lists have the same size. But if the latest list's size increases then all the elements gets out of order for example

```
a    a

b    b

c    c

d    z

e    d

f    e

g    f
```

As you can see if a new elements gets inserted in the second list then all the elements after that will be out of order. I cant seem to find a way to get around this while keeping the computational time as less as possible. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is this only for the previous frame, or any previous frame over some timespan?

Comment: 1) Please format your code with indentation. 2) Do you know that *z* has been inserted, or is it a surprise? If it's a surprise, is it just one item inserted, or many? Are they all in one spot or sprinkled around? All these things affect how to do it.

Comment: just the previous frame.

Comment: You are right Mike. I will keep that in mind the next time. You did not have to be rude about it actually :)
No i dont know if z is inserted. It cant be multiple items and they can be at any spot in my vector. sprinkled as you said.

Comment: [`std::mismatch`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/mismatch) ?

Comment: If insertions like *z* are only single items, surrounded in each case by items from the original list, comparison is easy. At each step, compare the current item. If it matches, fine. If it doesn't match, move one step ahead and see if that matches. If it does, fine, you've got an insertion. If not, fail.

Comment: Ok, so you have large chunks of meta data that you don't want to move. Why not create two `std::vector<BigObject*>`s and then use [`std::set_difference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference)?

Answer (score 1):

1) In most cases `std::vector` is faster than `std::list` due to processor's cache usage.

2) Sort both arrays. Insert the new element in the correct position to 
keep the sorted order.

3) Use binary search to check the presence of an element from vector2 in the vector1.

The complexity should be `M * log(N)`, where N is the length of the first vector and M is the length of the second one.

Answer (score 0):

In the following program the copy and move constructors and assignment operators are deleted to ensure we don't copy or move the large objects. Sorting is only done on the pointers once per frame and should require minimal time.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

class MyBigObject {
public:
    MyBigObject(char name) : name{name} {};
    MyBigObject(const MyBigObject&) = delete;
    MyBigObject(MyBigObject&&) = delete;
    MyBigObject& operator=(const MyBigObject&) = delete;
    MyBigObject& operator=(MyBigObject&&) = delete;

    bool operator< (const MyBigObject& rhs) const
    {
        return name < rhs.name;
    }

    char name;
    char bigdata[100000];
};

void doSomething(const MyBigObject& object)
{
    std::cout << "Working on object that was added:" << object.name << '\n';
}


void calculate_frame(const std::set<MyBigObject>& objects)
{
    static std::vector<const MyBigObject*> last_frame_objects;
    std::vector<const MyBigObject*> new_frame_objects;
    std::vector<const MyBigObject*> difference;
    std::for_each(objects.begin(),objects.end(),[&new_frame_objects](const MyBigObject& object) {new_frame_objects.push_back(&object); });
    std::sort(new_frame_objects.begin(),new_frame_objects.end());
    std::set_difference(new_frame_objects.begin(),new_frame_objects.end(),last_frame_objects.begin(),last_frame_objects.end(),
        std::inserter(difference,difference.begin()));
    for (auto object_ptr : difference) {
        doSomething(*object_ptr);
    }
    last_frame_objects = new_frame_objects;
}

int main()
{
    std::set<MyBigObject> objects;
    std::cout << "Start of frame\n";
    objects.emplace('a');
    objects.emplace('b');
    objects.emplace('c');
    calculate_frame(objects);
    std::cout << "Start of frame\n";
    objects.emplace('d');
    objects.emplace('e');
    objects.emplace('f');
    calculate_frame(objects);
    std::cout << "Start of frame\n";
    objects.erase('a');
    objects.erase('c');
    calculate_frame(objects);
    std::cout << "Start of frame\n";
    objects.emplace('c');
    calculate_frame(objects);
    return 0;
}
```

Produces:

```
Start of frame
Working on object that was added:a
Working on object that was added:b
Working on object that was added:c
Start of frame
Working on object that was added:d
Working on object that was added:e
Working on object that was added:f
Start of frame
Start of frame
Working on object that was added:c
```